# Sound properties manipulation in python

Tags: python, scientific-computing, audio

I am searching for a lib that helps me to use many sound properties.

I mean, I need something to get each frequency of sounds, get the sound waves length and width, get the peak and trough (in a measurement way) of the sounds.

I need something that leads me as close as possible to manipulate and measure sounds waves in some ways, this is something that I need more for a scientific research than for an application.

It is hard to find something like that, If you could help me with some links or anything, would be a great help for me.

If you have something even in other languages, it could help me.

I will keep this question updated as I find answers as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python wiki page [PythonInMusic](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic) has a lot of links, some of which will probably be useful to you. It includes a whole range of projects to input and output sound in different formats. A quick glance shows a couple of more specialised projects that might also be helpful:

- [audiolab](http://www.ar.media.kyoto-u.ac.jp/members/david/softwares/audiolab/) - bridges the gap between numpy and sound formats
- [musickit](http://musickit.sourceforge.net/) - support for signal processing, and apparently used in 'scientific experiments'

These will probably give you the tools to read sounds in and convert them into a useful form for analysis.

After that, it seems to me that what you are describing is more about signal/waveform analysis, than sound per se, so that may be a more helpful direction to search in. I'm not aware of any Python package that does exactly what you're looking for. Measurement of things like wavelength, peak and trough doesn't sound particularly difficult to me though - you could look at coding your own routines for this using SciPy.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will have a look at these links and SciPy as well.